# Meaning of escaped and unescaped value in context of ejs templating engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

<%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template

What these 2 lines means specifically the 'escaped' and 'unescaped' word?

Comment: When you escape some HTML code, it actually renders it into HTML safe string. Take a look at this https://www.w3school.com.cn/jsref/jsref_escape.asp should help you understand it. The point of doing it is, mainly to avoid code that might cause a security problem on your web page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me show you a simple example.

Let's say you have data stored in your database and want to render it in a view ejs page. Example:

```
x = "<p>This is a paragraph</p>"
```

Now add the these lines in your ejs page

```
<%= x %>
<%- x %>
```

You are going to see this

> ```
> <p>This is a paragraph</p> 
> This is a paragraph
> ```

As you see, `<%=` tag escapes the html tags, and does not let them to be translated. 
The opposite happens with `<%-` tag, where html is translated (unescaped), and you see the result you wish.

`<%=` tag escapes that code for security reasons. In case you want to use `<%-` tag you have to be sure about the data you store on your database and want later render them.

Think about this data

```
x = "<script>alert('You are in danger!')</script>"
```

And try to render it this way

```
<%- x %>
```

Guess what! You are going to see a nice alert message informing you that if you aren't sure about your data, you are in danger.

Hope I helped you.